# How to speed up Fluid Simulation Baking time (with moving parts)?

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation

I am animating a machine that shows high pressure water running inside of the machine.

With resolution for the sim set about 150, it takes half an hour to get to 9% and then slows down almost to a stop once the fluid reaches any moving parts. I have tried lower resolutions but then the fluid does not flow through the components correctly. My testing indicates this time will only increase when I increase the amount of water coming from my inflow, which I hope to do later.

Alternatively, please let me known if there is no way to optimize the baking time.

Blender file: https://ufile.io/b420e

[image]

UPDATE: Baked the sim overnight and only 65% is done in the morning.